# Cannot catch exception inside map function

Tags: function, clojure, exception

I'm trying to catch an exception that is thrown by a function passed to a map function but it isn't caught. I don't understand why.

Example:

```
(defn x [x]
  (throw (Exception. "An exception")))

(try
  (map x '(1 2 3))
  (catch Exception e "caught exception"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are being hit by lazyness. Remember, `map` returns a lazy `seq`, therefore `x` isn't run until something tries to access the first element of that `seq`.

Your example will work if you realize it with some `fn`, let's say `doall`, or `first`, like so:

```
(try
  (doall (map x [1 2 3]))
  (catch Exception e "Caught!"))
```

Then why do you receive the exception at all? Well since no exceptions are raised, the `try` block returns the lazy `seq`, which your REPL will try to print out, calling `x` for you.